# How to copy a specific area in a 3d map?

Tags: 3d-view

I bought a 3D map of whole hong kong city but only specific area is needed. (i have attached an example photo for your easy reference)

Any chances to copy the selected area and save it as another 3D object file?

My purpose is to put it in powerpoint as a 3D object, for presentation use.
(as you can imagine, the original file size is too large, not feasible to put the whole city map into a powerpoint)

Thank you so much for your help!

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Blender.SE! What do you exactly mean by "cut down"? What are you not able to do? Are you not able to separate the pieces?

Comment: Thank you for your reply :), I have updated my question. Appreciate if you could take a look at it, thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Your request it's not so clear, but I'll try anyway.

- press <kbd>Tab</kbd> to get into **Edit Mode**
- press <kbd>Num 7</kbd>, <kbd>Num 5</kbd> to get in **Top ortographic** view
- press the **X-Ray** button (in the picture)
- press <kbd>B</kbd> and drag with the mouse to select the areas you want to delete (or use the circle selection tool with <kbd>C</kbd>)
- press <kbd>Del</kbd> (the "delete" button, which has different names in different countries) and choose *Vertices*

[image]

- keep doing that until you get the area you want, and try to cut along streets or parks, so that you don't cut buildings in half
- press <kbd>Tab</kbd> to get back into **Object Mode**
- select your model and export it from the *File > Export* menu

If you want to make a game or something else and you need the map to be closed (so a smaller map instead of a portion of a bigger one), you need to create some natural barriers, like walls, mountains or sea, on the edges of the map.

While doing that you need to re-route the severed streets (just copy-paste the existing ones)

Comment: Many thanks for your detailed reply, really really appreciated!! and sorry for making my question unclear. I have updated my question, could you please help to take a look, many thanks again!

Comment: I can't see any update on the question...

Comment: can you see it now?

Comment: I can see it now.
My advice is the same of the answer I wrote: from the **Top Ortographic View**, using **X-Ray**, select all you want to delete (or select the are you want and then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> to invert the selection) using the box or circle tools, delete them and you are done: export the final object in .obj , or any other 3D format you like

Comment: Thanks again for your reply and it works! However, as you can see from my screenshot, the map has so many layers, any chances to group all of them as one single layer?

Comment: in Objet mode you could select the are you want to keep and invert it with Ctrl+I, thene delete all objects. This should delete all objects outside your area. Then merge the remaining onesw with Ctrl+J and do the same trick in Edit Mode